# How to fix an Incorrect work of json.loads()

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am going to use json.loads(my_template) for my_template. My template contains different values including boolean value. Unfortunately for my bool values True or False I got lowercase true and false.How can I fix it?

```
import json
print json.loads({'foo': True}) # => {"foo": true}
```

Should be {"foo": True}

So i use jinja template and because of the above-mentioned reason I have to write the following:

```
{
  "private_af": {% if private_af %} true  {% elif not private_af %} false      {%endif %},
  "created": {{created}},
  "updated": {{updated}},
}
```

Comment: You don't have to / you can't. This how it is in JSON notation. Boolean are lower case. What is the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: I have expanded my descriptionCould you please take a look?

Comment: Not clear why you are using `json.loads()`. If you want to pass a dictionary to your template, then just pass the dict without converting it to json.